# (GTM) Trigger fb pixel on hover

Tags: jquery, facebook, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I'm trying to trigger a fb pixel event when hovering a div (or else) in a page. However it looks like the event is being triggered a first time before I hover the div. When hovering the div, the event indicates the right parameters.

A very good thing also, would be to have additional information captured like the hovered div id or else.

Here is the code I inserted in my GTM tag. I'm triggering it on page load (All Pages).

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
var startHover = $.now();

$("#product_name").hover(
function(){
    startHover = $.now();
},
function(){
    var endHover = $.now();
    var msHovered = endHover - startHover;
    var seconds = msHovered/1000;
    if (seconds >= 1) {
        fbq('track', 'Hover', {
            domain: {{Page Hostname}},
            page_path: {{Page Path}}
        });
    }
}
);
});
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<p id="product_name">Product 1</p>
```

Any help would be really pleased!

Many thanks.

Comment: So the event is triggered on hovering for first time only and not on subsequent events,is it the case?

Comment: No, actually the event is being triggered 1sec after the page loaded whatsoever you hover or not. Then when hovering #product_name, the fb pixel parameters are properly sent to the event. The desired behaviour is to have the fb pixel only triggered after hovering the #product_name div for 1sec, not one second after page load.

Comment: there is something incorrect with hover,even when mouse is hovered anywhere on page,it registers it as hover.Try this https://jsfiddle.net/L9ory5ym/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my problem. Basically I was triggering the tag on All Pages, so the fb event was triggered without content, the correct parameters being only sent when hovering #product_name.

I created a variable "event" and pushed a dataLayer "thereisHover".

```
dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'thereisHover'
});
```

Then I separated the standard event into another tag which fires only when event = thereisHover.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, i understand that you want to trigger fb event only if someone hover `#product_name` more than 1 sec.

In your HTML code please use this code:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var timer;
        $("#product_name").mouseenter(function() {
            var that = this;
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                //var text = $(that).text() //text inside hovered #product_name element
                //var textInSpan =  $(that).find('span').text() //text inside hovered #product_name span element
                //var hoveredId =  $(that).attr('id') //hovered element ID
                //var hoveredClass =  $(that).attr('class') //hovered element class name
                fbq('track', 'Hover', {
                    domain: {{Page Hostname}},
                    page_path: {{Page Path}}
                });
            }, 1000);
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my code i added commented samples how you can receive additional information about hovered div information

Comment: Hello Victor! Thank you for your code! Unfortunately it seems like it behaves as mine: the event is still being fired a first time 1sec after page load, which is sending wrong information to facebook until you hover #product_name, where the good parameters are added to the event. Could we get rid of the page load fire and only trigger the event when actually hovering #product_name ?

Comment: Hmm, i can't believe into that. May be other tag is firing and sending wrong info to FB?

Comment: Yes I don't understand. I'm using your code now as it looks more proper than mine, but it seems like it's being triggered after 1sec anywhere my cursor is, even if out of the #product_name paragraph

Answer (score 0):

As I see it your `<p>` element stretches across the whole width of the page and hence even if you do not hover over exact element but just the cross section containing the `<p>`,u register a hover event.

Check this to see the inconsistency https://jsfiddle.net/L9ory5ym/1/
[image: JsFiddle screenshot]
To fix this add `width` attribute to the paragraph element,to register event only on the concerned element.

Comment: Hello Shivam. Indeed your observation is right, I will add a width to the paragraph. However, the event is still being triggered even if I don't hover on that line. It is systematically being triggered 1sec after page load, wherever my cursor is.

Comment: Can you probably put a debug point on ur code where the 1 sec check is tested.Probably this block is being executed somewhere else in page,may be some duplicate code somewhere else on code

Comment: Seems like you are right. If I don't put my mouse within the window area, nothing is being triggered.

Comment: Please further verify the behaviour and reply back for any updates.Kindly accept the answer if it solves your issue